# Unable to display children:Attribute not found: value

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I keep on getting this error when trying to view objects in the Debugger in PyCharm:

**Unable to display children:Attribute not found: value**

I have deduced that it is an error with Pycharm itself, not my code

(I get the same error on multiple scripts, but no error on with an older version of Pycharm on 2 different computers)

I'm on PyCharm Community 2017.3.4

Any ideas for workarounds, other than installing an older version?

Comment: Everything works fine on version 2016.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I am finding similar issues.  I too think there is something up with PyCharm it does not work as expected or previous version as you mention.  I also found  Pyscripter to debug as expected.

In some instances I would rely on the result object, result[0] or result.getOutput(0) to pass to next tool. Instead one can use a variable for the "output" or use the string (name) directly as input for the next tool.

For example,

```
facility_staging_polygons = os.path.join(outGDB, 'facility_staging_polygons\Polygon_1')
result = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(facility_staging_polygons, 'facility_staging_polygons_Layer')

# Process: Update Attributes
arcpy.AddField_management('facility_staging_polygons_Layer', "area_calc", "LONG")
```